# Kotlin Flows map

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, kotlin-flow

I have an issue regarding kotlin flow merging.
See below fun.

```
suspend fun method(filter: String): Flow<List<Model>> {

// Search.
val models: List<Model> = repo.getModels(filter)  // suspend function

// Get favorites
val favoritesFlow: Flow<List<Int>> = otherRepo.getFavorites()

// Return models as Flow, but mark/unmark every model as favorite when favoritesFlow is updated.
??? val result = models + favoritesFlow ????

    return result
}
```

I need to return a flow of list of models, but when the favorite flow is changed, I have to mark or unmark each model as favorite.
Do you have any idea how could I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by marking model as favourate? Do you mean to change a property? And inside comment you said change every model while in post you mentioned each model, do you want to perform action against ints (as index of models) coming from flow?

Answer (score 5):

You can combine emited values from both flows using Flow.combine()

```
fun favoriteModels() : Flow<List<Model>> = repo.getModels(filter)
    .combine(otherRepo.getFavorites()) { models, favorites ->
        models.filter { model -> favorites.contains(model.id) }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` or `mapLatest` functions to transform `favorites` into `models`, something like this:

```
fun method(filter: String): Flow<List<Model>> = otherRepo.getFavorites().mapLatest { favorites ->
    val models: List<Model> = repo.getModels(filter)  
    // do something with the models and favorites
    models
}
```